# NX Cypress builder not loading components due to wrong path

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress, nrwl-nx

I'm having issues running `e2e` when building my application with the `@nrwl/cypress` builder that I can't quite figure out.

I'm using a component library which is fine with the `angular-devkit` builder, but when using `@nrwl/cypress`, it seems webpack attempts to load these components from a relative path instead of the project root.

So, any components on the landing page will load fine but when I navigate to a different route, this route is used as the app base and my components fail to load.

I can't say for sure this is an issue with `@nrwl/cypress`, only that it isn't happening with the `angular-devkit` builder.

Some config:

```
"myapp-e2e": {
    "root": "apps/myapp-e2e",
    "sourceRoot": "apps/myapp-e2e/src",
    "projectType": "application",
    "architect": {
      "e2e": {
        "builder": "@nrwl/cypress:cypress",
        "options": {
          "cypressConfig": "apps/myapp-e2e/cypress.json",
          "tsConfig": "apps/myapp-e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
          "devServerTarget": "myapp:serve"
        },
        "configuration": {
          "production": {
            "devServerTarget": "myapp:serve:production"
          }
        }
      },
      "lint": {
        "builder": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
        "options": {
          "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/myapp-e2e/**/*.{js,ts}"]
        }
      }
    },
    "tags": [],
    "implicitDependencies": ["myapp"]
  },
```

**cypress.json**

```
{
  "fileServerFolder": ".",
  "fixturesFolder": "./src/fixtures",
  "integrationFolder": "./src/integration",
  "modifyObstructiveCode": false,
  "pluginsFile": "./src/plugins/index",
  "supportFile": "./src/support/index.ts",
  "video": false,
  "videosFolder": "../../dist/cypress/apps/myapp-e2e/videos",
  "screenshotsFolder": "../../dist/cypress/apps/myapp-e2e/screenshots",
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "pageLoadTimeout": 120000,
  "viewportWidth": 2100,
  "viewportHeight": 1080,
  "env": {
    "entitlements_url": "/entitlementapi/entitlements/"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.e2e.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "allowJs": true,
    "types": ["cypress", "node"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.js"]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress"]
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't know about `angular-devkit` but from the configs provided you have old versions of Nx and Cypress. I'd start with an upgrade to the latest.

Comment: As per documentation (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/legacy-configuration#Folders-Files) cypress.json goes normally to root folder and any paths are used without dot notation, only giving sub folder paths related to the root. My strong guess is that the dot notation as a fileServerFolder for example gets now redefined on each location and dot is calculated again on every location.

Comment: try configuring your paths with `./../` instead of `../../`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the baseHref property was not being set in the nx e2e project but it was set using the standard dev build.

I discovered this when I bumped the app to angular 14 and it complained about the baseHref flag. When I removed it I discovered the components were not loading even using the angular dev build in the same way the cypress builder was having issues.

Adding baseHref="/" to the cypress project build config resolved the issue.

Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the @nrwl/cypress builder is using webpack to bundle the application and it is not able to resolve the paths in the tsconfig.json file.

The solution is to add the paths to the tsconfig.json file and then use the @myapp/* syntax to import the components.

This is not a problem with the angular-devkit builder because it is not using webpack to bundle the application.

Ttry to add this to your tsconfig.json:

```
"paths": {
  "@myapp/*": ["libs/myapp/*"]
}
```

and then import your components like this

```
import { MyComponent } from '@myapp/my-component';
```